# Java: Protocol Buffer does not generate parsing functions

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I've the following .proto file:

```
message MediatorMessageMsg{
    required double speed = 1;
    required double heading = 2;

    required string sender = 3;
}
```

and I use Eclipse Mars with Protocol Buffer 2.5.0 version. It generates the necessary file (which we are not supposed to edit) however I cannot use the important functions of

- writeDelimitedTo()
- parseDelimitedFrom()
- newBuilder().set...

without these there is simply no point in using the entire thing. I checked the file and I can see parseDelimitedFrom() there, however I cannot call it in my own project (Yes, imported already). When I hover my mouse on the error, it gives me the following:

```
The method parseDelimitedFrom(ByteArrayInputStream) is undefined for the type MediatorMessage
```

Anyone has an idea why is this the case?

**EDIT:** Some more details regarding the question.

I cannot use the function below, for instance, to build my message. It raises an error.

```
MediatorMessage mediatorMessage = MediatorMessage.newBuilder().
```

or I cannot do this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufferSize);
mediatorMessage.writeDelimitedTo(output);
```

or this

```
ByteArrayInputStream firstInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
mediatorMessageOne = MediatorMessage.parseDelimitedFrom(firstInput);
```

So these functions are not recognized for some reason.

Comment: Your question is missing some details. Could you please post the code which produces this warning. Including the type of all involved variables. In your question you posted to definition of `MediatorMessageMsg` and in the cited error it mention `MediatorMessage`.

Comment: This is not a runtime error, I cannot even compile since the functions are not recognized. And I gave the function names which are not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you still have not answered how your `MediatorMessageMsg` from the `*.proto` file becomes `MediatorMessage.java` find below a stripped down example. Which should point you in the right direction.

Assume following directory and file structure, `protoc` is assumed to be installed and in your `PATH`.

```
bin/
lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
src/Check.java
MediatorMessage.proto
```

**src/Check.java**

```
import com.google.protobuf.TextFormat;
import sub.optimal.MediatorMessage.MediatorMessageMsg;

class Check {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        MediatorMessageMsg.Builder builder = MediatorMessageMsg.newBuilder();
        MediatorMessageMsg msg = builder.setSpeed(42.0)
                .setHeading(0.0)
                .setSender("foobar")
                .build();

        System.out.println(TextFormat.shortDebugString(msg));
    }
}
```

**MediatorMessage.proto**

```
option java_package = "sub.optimal";
option java_outer_classname = "MediatorMessage";

message MediatorMessageMsg{
    required double speed = 1;
    required double heading = 2;

    required string sender = 3;
}
```

- generate Java source from proto file

  ```
  protoc --java_out=src/ MediatorMessage.proto
  ```

  this generates the Java source file `src/sub/optimal/MediatorMessage.java`.
- compile the Java sources

  ```
  javac -cp lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:src/. -d bin/ src/Check.java
  ```

  this generates the files

  ```
  bin/Check.class
  bin/sub/optimal/MediatorMessage$1.class
  bin/sub/optimal/MediatorMessage$MediatorMessageMsg$1.class
  bin/sub/optimal/MediatorMessage$MediatorMessageMsg$Builder.class
  bin/sub/optimal/MediatorMessage$MediatorMessageMsg.class
  bin/sub/optimal/MediatorMessage$MediatorMessageMsgOrBuilder.class
  bin/sub/optimal/MediatorMessage.class
  ```
- run the simple check

  ```
  java -cp lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:bin/ Check
  ```

output

```
speed: 42.0 heading: 0.0 sender: "foobar"
```

Comment: Okay I was confused by the names `MediatorMessage` and `MediatorMessageMsg`. Now everything works. Thank you.